# Does the resistor value on D+ and D- line matter on Arduinos?

Tags: arduino, resistors, usb, usb-device

I noticed from looking at the different Arduino boards schematic, there are 22 ohm resistors in series between the D+/D- pins from the USB port to the ATMega IC.

A snippet of the schematic of the Leonardo below:
[image]

However, the Sparkfun Qwiic Pro Micro USB-C schematic has 5.1K resistors instead (picture below).  This made me think; **does the value of the resistors on the D+ and D- line have to be within the 22 ohm range?** **What happens if there is no resistor or the resistor value is really high (over 10k)?**

[image]

Comment: Different resistor; different reason.

Comment: It is not a board question it is a part question read the datasheet for the part.  Understand that existing products can and have at times been done incorrectly, yet still go out into the market.  Dont assume an existing board design for a product is correct.  That is not the proper source of information for the design requirements.  Yes there are usb spec requirements (more required reading for doing a board design) and some vendors parts handle some of these items on chip others require it to be off chip.

Comment: @old_timer both schematic above uses the ATMega32U4. I took your advice on looking at the datasheet on it and it said to connect 22 ohm resistor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What happens if there is no resistor or the resistor value is really high (over 10k)?

The USB connection won't work. Remember that there are pulldown resistors in the hub/host with about 20k ohms.

The 5.1K value for R8 and R9 on the Qwiic Pro is a slight mistake in the schematic - these resistors use the same *footprint* as others but should have a different ohms value. The vendor has omitted the BOM (bill of materials) for this product, so we would need to *measure* on a finished PCB for the *actual* value - which I'm pretty sure is 22 ohms.

Comment: Oh I see. I just made my own Arduino using the 5.1K resitor on the D+/D- pin (as I had those resistors but not 22 ohm ones). I can upload the arduino bootloader to it via ArduinoISP but when I connect it to the computer via USB, the computer doesn't recognize it. I think this might be the reason then.